# Perplexing pandas index change after left merge

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame and I am interested in a particular row. When I run

```python
questionnaire_events[questionnaire_events['event_id'].eq(6506308)]
```

I get the row, and its index is 7,816. I then merge questionnaire_events with another data frame

```python
merged = questionnaire_events.merge(
    ordinals,
    how='left',
    left_on='event_id',
    right_on='id')
```

(It is worth noting that the ordinals data frame has no NaNs and no duplicated ids, but questionnaire_events does have some rows with NaN values for event_id.)

```python
merged[merged['event_id'].eq(6506308)]
```

The resulting row has index 7,581. Why? What has happened in the merge, a left outer merge, to mean that my row has moved from 7,816 to 7,581? If there were multiple rows with the same id in the ordinals data frame then I can see how the merged data frame would have more rows than the left data frame in the merge, but that is not the case, so why has the row moved?

(N.B. Sorry I cannot give a crisp code sample. When I try to produce test data the row index change does not happen, it is only happening on my real data.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pd.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) does not preserve the original datafame indexes.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key':[*'ABCDE'], 'val':[1,2,3,4,5]}, index=[100,200,300,400,500])

print('df1 dataframe:')
print(df1)
print('\n')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key':[*'AZCWE'], 'val':[10,20,30,40,50]}, index=[*'abcde'])
print('df2 dataframe:')
print(df2)
print('\n')

df_m = df1.merge(df2, on='key', how='left')
print('df_m dataframe:')
print(df_m)
```

Now, if your df1 is the default range index, then it is possible that you could get different index in your merged dataframe. If you subset or filter your df1, then your indexing will not match.

## Work Around:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df_m2 = df1.merge(df2, on='key', how='left')
df_m2 = df_m2.set_index('index')
print('df_m2 work around dataframe:')
print(df_m2)
```

Output:

```
df_m2 work around dataframe:
      key  val_x  val_y
index                  
100     A      1   10.0
200     B      2    NaN
300     C      3   30.0
400     D      4    NaN
500     E      5   50.0
```

Comment: Thank you, so `df1['blah'] = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left')['blah']` will sometimes produce unexpected results

Comment: @dumbledad I decided to add a work around for what you are seeing.